# Сообщение "Версия браузера устарела"

Tags: всплывающее-окно, обновление, html, javascript, браузер

Вопрос остался открытым и нерешенным.
Вот его суть:

Мне нужно вывести всплывающий блок на HTML странице с просьбой обновить свой браузер, если его версия ниже обозначенной мной.

Я находил скрипт вывода диалогового Alert-окна, которое предлагает обновить браузер до новой версии, однако это мне не подходит. Мне нужно, чтобы в нужном месте на странице отображался красиво оформленный DIV-блок, а не просто сообщение с ошибкой.

Вот скрипт с Alert-окном (последние 2 примера): [Определение браузера и его версии](http://www.xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/browser-detect/browser-name-and-version.html).

Такой вариант смотрится абсолютно не красиво и может отпугнуть пользователя.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что нужно заменить, чтобы вместо сообщения с ошибкой отображался скрытый DIV-блок?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос получил мною комментарий "бессмысленный" ввиду того, что задача сводится к замене

```
alert( "Ваш браузер устарел" );
```

на

```
document.getElementById( "myBeautifulDiv" ).style.display = "block";
```

где `myBeautifulDiv` это красивый блок с уведомлением.
Решение никак не связано с описанной проблемой и относится к основам языка.